# How do I use FTP in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, ftp

I am new in Flex Environment, specifically flex3. I've been studying it for 1 week.
I have a project which I need FTP to upload and download mp3 and pictures files.

What is the best way to get started?

Comment: is this still an issue? otherwise mark the answer as 'accepted' so that this question doesn't show up under 'unsanswered'. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean creating an FTP client in Flex, it has been done already:

[FlexFTP](http://projects.maliboo.pl/FlexFTP/)

Comment: please tell me how should it be done. i've got same problem posted at this link 
http://www.mail-archive.com/flexcoders@yahoogroups.com/msg81629.html

Comment: Use the FTPClient class from the link posted above.

Answer (score 1):

I used this 2 years ago. It works great but only one thing is missing, and it makes it impossible to use for big files (more than 10 or 50 Mo).

In fact, sockets in Flex have a buffer you can write into, so that data will be sent. But you can not determine how much of the buffer has been sent, nor if it is empty.

So the progress of an upload or the upload completion is impossible to retrieve with flex... maliboo has made an approximation in the pl.maliboo.ftp.invokers.UploadInv class. He sends 4096 every 300 ms, and considere that it is ok.

And this will always be true, because it is the worst case, but when you upload 3Go with a good connection speed, the script will run forever, also the upload is finished.